# Underscore JS find Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, underscore.js

I have an array like follows

```html
var goal  = [

    {
        "category" : "education",
        "title" : "Charlie University",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "date" : "01/03/2020",
        "value" : 50000,
        "achievability" : 3,
        "experimental_achievability": 3,
        "designation": "{"id":1, "jobCode":1003}",
        "suggested": false,
        "accounts": [],
        "articles": [],
        "related_goals": [],
        "id":"1"
    },
    {
        "category" : "education",
        "title" : "Charlie University",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "date" : "01/03/2020",
        "value" : 50000,
        "achievability" : 3,
        "experimental_achievability": 3,
        "designation": "{"id":2, "jobCode":1004}",
        "suggested": false,
        "accounts": [],
        "articles": [],
        "related_goals": [],
        "id":"2"
    },
    ]
```

How can i fetch the object which is having property `"designation": "{"id":2, "jobCode":1004}",` from goal array using underscore JS.

Can i use _.findWhere for this?

Comment: I've assumed that your "using Underscore" was just because you thought Underscore was needed. It isn't, JavaScript's own standard library is more than up to this job. But if you really wanted to use Underscore, not the standard library, please just say so. (I expect there's a dupetarget for that, too...)

Comment: Your array is actually invalid.

Comment: (I've added an Underscore-specific dupetarget.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need underscore for this, you can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
goal.find(function(item) {
  return item.id === 2 && item.jobCode === 1004
})
```

es2015 example:

```js
goal.find(item => item.id === 2 && item.jobCode === 1004)
```

Comment: The OP was clear that they want to use underscore. If not using underscore, then this is a duplicate for dozens of questions. Rather than answering it, it would be appropriate to pick a duplicate.